# How can updating hash attribute, updates other hash attributes in Perl Moose

Tags: perl, moose

Here hash2 attribute is dependent on hash1. infact, hash2 is driven by hash1. for example,

hash1 -> key1 => value1, key2 => value2 etc..

hash2 -> key1 => 6, key2 => 6 etc. it is length(value from hash1, going to hash2)

Tried something like below, but not helpful.

```
has 'hash1' => (
    is        => 'rw',
    isa       => 'HashRef[Str]',
    default   => sub { {} },
    handles   => {
        map { $_ . '_hash1' => $_ } @hash_delegations
    },
);

has 'hash2' => (
    is        => 'rw',
    isa       => 'HashRef',
    builder   => '_filter_hash1',
    handles   => {
        map { $_ . 'hash2' => $_ } @hash_delegations
    },
);

sub _filter_hash1 {
    my $self = shift;
    for my $alias ($self->keys_hash1()) {
        return {$alias, length($alias)};
    }
}
```

Hash1 is going to set over time, not sure how to make sure that how should I capture the event on hash1 to update the entry in the hash2. Any idea how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example which uses read-only hashes with triggers and method modifiers...

```perl
package MyApp;

use Z qw( Dumper );
use Hash::Util qw( unlock_ref_keys lock_ref_keys );

class '::My::Object' => sub {
    my %common = (
        is       => 'rw',
        isa      => HashRef[Str],
        trigger  => sub { lock_ref_keys($_[1]) },
        default  => sub { lock_ref_keys(my $ref = {}); $ref },
        handles_via => 'Hash',
    );
    
    has hash1 => (
        %common,
        handles  => [
            'set_hash1' => 'set',
            'get_hash1' => 'get',
        ],
    );
    
    has hash2 => (
        %common,
        isa      => HashRef[Int],
        handles  => [
            'set_hash2' => 'set',
            'get_hash2' => 'get',
        ],
    );
    
    around set_hash1 => sub {
        my ( $next, $self, $key, $val ) = ( shift, shift, @_ );
        unlock_ref_keys( $self->hash1 );
        unlock_ref_keys( $self->hash2 );
        my $r = $self->$next( @_ );
        $self->set_hash2( $key, length($val) );
        lock_ref_keys( $self->hash1 );
        lock_ref_keys( $self->hash2 );
        return $r;
    };
    
    method BUILD => sub {
        my ( $self, $args ) = @_;
        if ( my $h1 = $args->{hash1} ) {
            $self->set_hash1( $_, length $h1->{$_} ) for keys %$h1;
        }
    };
};

my $obj = 'My::Object'->new(
    hash1 => { foo => 'xyzzy' },
);
$obj->set_hash1('bar', 'quux');

print Dumper($obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to create a cache of value lengths? In practice, [length](http://p3rl.org/length) is so fast you don't need to cache it, but it might be just a simplified example of something more complex. I'd use a **trigger**, plus a trait on the first hash to enforce setting the value via a method. Changing the hash value directly wouldn't trigger the change in the other attribute.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

{   package My::Object;
    use Moose;

    my @hash_delegations = qw( keys );

    has 'hash1' => (
        is      => 'rw',
        isa     => 'HashRef[Str]',
        default => sub { {} },
        trigger => \&_update_hash2,
        traits  => ['Hash'],
        handles => { set_hash1 => 'set' },
    );

    has 'hash2' => (
        is     => 'ro',
        writer => '_set_hash2',
        isa    => 'HashRef',
    );

    sub _update_hash2 {
        my ($self, $new, $old) = @_;
        $self->_set_hash2({ map { $_ => length $self->hash1->{$_} }
                            keys %{ $self->hash1 }});
    }
}

my $o = 'My::Object'->new(hash1 => {a => 42, b => 'Universe'});
say $o->hash2->{$_} for qw( a b );

$o->set_hash1(c => '0123456789');
say $o->hash2->{c};

$o->hash1->{c} = "";  # Wrong!
say $o->hash2->{c};   # Didn't change :-(
```